# How to set heading of agentset from nest in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

What I'm planning to do is to ask a group of agentsets to flock from nest throughout world.

I'm using flocking codes and I have problem to identify heading for cohere part. Since all agents are moving from nest, how can I set their heading?

The error I got after editing my codes are :

```
No heading is defined from a point (0,0) to that same point.
error while turtle 1 running TOWARDS
  called by procedure AVERAGE-HEADING-TOWARDS-FLOCKMATES
  called by procedure COHERE
  called by procedure FLOCK
```

Here is code for agentset:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  let number-of-groups 3
  let turtles-per-group 4  
  create-turtles turtles-per-group * number-of-groups 
    [ set color red  
      set size 1.5  
      set pen-mode "down"
    ]  
  set groups [] ; empty list
  repeat number-of-groups [
    let new-group n-of turtles-per-group turtles with [
      not is-agentset? my-group
    ]
    ask new-group [ set my-group new-group ]
    set groups lput new-group groups
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
ask turtles [flock]
end
```

Here is flocking part

```
to flock
  find-flockmates
  if any? flockmates
  [
    find-nearest-neighbor
    ifelse distance nearest-neighbor < minimum-separation
        [ separate ]
        [ align
          cohere ] ]
end

to find-flockmates  ;; turtle procedure
  set flockmates my-group
end

to find-nearest-neighbor ;; turtle procedure
  set nearest-neighbor min-one-of flockmates [distance myself]
end

;;; COHERE

to cohere  
  turn-towards average-heading-towards-flockmates max-cohere-turn
end

to-report average-heading-towards-flockmates  
 let x-component mean [sin (towards myself + 180)] of flockmates
  let y-component mean [cos (towards myself + 180)] of flockmates
  ifelse x-component = 0 and y-component = 0
    [ report heading ]
    [ report atan x-component y-component ]
end
```

I have problems to change code for `to-report average-heading-towards-flockmates`  since `towards myself + 180)] of flockmates` cannot be use here. Can anyone help me?

Comment: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#other